# Не работает шрифт Google Fonts

Tags: html, css

Добрый день.  
Использую шрифт Fira Sans.

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?    family=Fira+Sans:300,400,500,700,300italic,400italic,500italic,700italic&subset=latin,cyrillic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Подключаю таким способом. 
Пример css:

```
font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
font-weight: 400;
font-style: italic;
```

На телефоне работает, на моём работает, на соседних нет. У кого-то работает, у кого опять же нет. В чём проблема? Заранее спасибо.

Адрес сайта: [**bm.webbys.ru**](http://bm.webbys.ru)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте добавить "s" в протоколе `http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?    family=Fira+Sans:300,400,500,700,300italic,400italic,500italic,700italic&subset=latin,cyrillic'`, чтобы получилось `https://`

Comment: Не помогло, к сожалению((

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй через @import
И еще попробуй с body убрать определение шрифта, вообще другие шрифты убери, кроме твоего, и посмотри.

Comment: Не помогло, и вроде нет шрифтов на боди)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте добавить в head:

```
<link href='https://code.cdn.mozilla.net/fonts/fira.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
```

Answer (score 0):

Может поможет пример как я подключал шрифт для странички:

```
body { font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif; }
@font-face {font-family: 'PT Sans'; 
    src: url('../fonts/pts55f_w.eot'); 
    src: local('PT Sans'), url('../fonts/PTS55F_W.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/PTS55F_W.woff') format('woff'),url('../fonts/PTS55F_W.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/PTS55F_W.svg#PTSans-Regular') format('svg');}
```